# FluentMigrator Migration From Application_Start

Tags: azure, migration, fluent-migrator

I am currently changing our database deployment strategy to use FluentMigration and have been reading up on how to run this.  Some people have suggested that it can be run from Application_Start, I like this idea but other people are saying no but without specifying reasons so my questions are:

1. Is it a bad idea to run the database migration on application start and if so why?
2. We are planning on moving our sites to deploying to azure cloud services and if we don't run the migration from application_start how should/when should we run it considering we want to make the deployment as simple as possible.
3. Where ever it is run how do we ensure it is running only once as we will have a website and multiple worker roles as well (although we could just ensure the migration code is only called from the website but in the future we may increase to 2 or more instances, will that mean that it could run more than once?)

I would appreciate any insight on how others handle the migration of the database during deployment, particularly from the perspective of deployments to azure cloud services.

EDIT:

Looking at the comment below I can see the potential problems of running during application_start, perhaps the issue is I am trying to solve a problem with the wrong tool, if FluentMigrator isn't the way to go and it may not be in our case as we have a large number of stored procedures, views, etc. so as part of the migration I was going to have to use SQL scripts to keep them at the right version and migrating down I don't think would be possible.

What I liked about the idea of running during Application_Start was that I could build a single deployment package for Azure and just upload it to staging and the database migration would be run and that would be it, rather thank running manual scripts, and then just swap into production.

Answer (score 1):

Running migrations during Application_Start can be a viable approach. Especially during development.

However there are some potential problems:

- Application_Start will take longer and FluentMigrator will be run every time the App Pool is recycled. Depending on your IIS configuration this could be several times a day.
- if you do this in production, users might be affected i.e. trying to access a table while it is being changed will result in an error.
- DBA's don't usually approve.
- What happens if the migrations fail on startup? Is your site down then?

My opinion ->

For a site with a decent amount of traffic I would prefer to have a build script and more control over when I change the database schema. For a hobby (or small non-critical project) this approach would be fine.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I see your point about it trying to run every time the app pool recycles but I guess if the migrations are already run it won't run anything although still a performance hit.  It could be that FluentMigrator isn't the way to go.  At present a deployment for us means using VS Database Project to build the scripts, running them manually and then copying the site and I have to do this for each customer so trying to find a way to make it a single deployment package for either Azure or self hosted IIS.

Comment: I am biased towards FluentMigrator but I really wouldn't recommend VS Database Project. I know of several people using the Application_Start approach so if it works in your context then use it. Just be aware of the pitfalls.

Comment: I haven't used Azure much but using a build script is a normal approach for deploying to Azure. I think nearly everything is possible to automate via PowerShell (setting up test environments etc).  Here is an intro: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/automate-everything

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that I've used in the past is to make your migrations non-breaking - that is you write your migrations in such a way they can be deployed before any code changes and work with the existing code. This way both code and migrations both can be deployed independently 95% of the time. For example instead of changing an existing stored procedure you create a new one or if you want to rename a table column you add a new one.

The benefits of this are:

- Your database changes can be applied before any code changes. You're then free to roll back any breaking code changes or breaking migrations.
- Breaking migrations won't take the existing site down.
- DBAs can run the migrations independently.